# Sencha Ext.plugin.PullRefresh

Tags: sencha-touch

I am having a problem on a list with sencha touch 2.3 . I have set the PullRefresh plugin on my app but when I pull my list down and release it the refreshFn is never called.
Here is my code:

```
plugins: [
        {   xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
            pullText: '',
            autoSnapBack : false,
            refreshFn: function(callback, plugin) {
                console.log("Pulled");
            },
        }
    ]
```

Many thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: Well I dont see any 'refreshFn' exists in the docs!

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace refreshFn: section with this:

```
listeners:{
    latestfetched: function(eOpts) {
        console.log("Pulled");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Function for Using `PullRefresh` `plugin` in `Sencha`.

```
plugins: [{
xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
pullRefreshText: 'Getting Refresh...',
refreshFn: function() {
    var store = Ext.getStore('Company');
    store.getProxy().setExtraParam(Sencha App.util.Config.currentCompany);
    Ext.Viewport.setMasked({
        xtype: 'loadmask'
    });
    store.load(function(records, operation, success) {
        Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
    });
}}]
```